# Jest Mock Service argument is not assignable

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, nestjs

I've a simple controller in my NestJs application.

```
@Post('/')
async create(@Body() createUserRequest: CreateUserRequest): Promise<User> {
  return await this.userService.create(createUserRequest);
}
```

My goal is to test this function using jest. As you can see the controller injects an instance of `UserService`. So I try to mock this service in my unit test. The test case looks like this.

```
describe('User Controller', () => {
  let userService: UserService;
  let userController: UserController;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
      controllers: [UserController],
      providers: [UserService],
    }).compile();

    userService = module.get<UserService>(UserService);
    userController = module.get<UserController>(UserController);
  });

  describe('create', () => {
    it('should return a user', async () => {
      const result = new User();

      jest.spyOn(userService, 'create').mockImplementation(() => result);

      expect(await userController.create(new CreateUserRequest())).toBe(result);
    });
  });
});
```

My problem is that `jest.spyOn` where the mocking happens produces an error.

```
No overload matches this call.
Overload 1 of 4, '(object: UserService, method: never): SpyInstance<never, never>', gave the following error.
Argument of type '"create"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
Overload 2 of 4, '(object: UserService, method: never): SpyInstance<never, never>', gave the following error.
Argument of type '"create"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
```

Has anyone an idea what is wrong with my mock? I took this approach from the [documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/testing).

Comment: Does your `UserService` depend on any other dependencies?

Comment: Yes it depends on a repository

Comment: Well, nest can't create the service because it needs the Repository. Since it can't create it, it gets set as `undefined`. Because it's undefined, jest can't spy on it

Comment: This is I think not the case as a mock implementation is provided that overrides the function in the user service. See [spyOn](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname) documentation at Jest docs.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the response you expected, however, you could achieve the same result implementing as below:

```js
// ...
describe('create', () => {
  it('should return a user', async () => {
    const result = new User();

    ((userService as unknown) as any).create = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(result);
    // Or to ensure that the value is only called once, 
    // go ahead and use 'mockResolvedValueOnce'

    expect(await userController.create(new CreateUserRequest())).toBe(result);
  });
});
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to spy on the userService.prototype, like this:

```js
  jest.spyOn(userService.prototype, 'create').mockImplementation(() => result);
```